# What is the difference between cut’s -b and -c option?

Tags: command-line, coreutils

I've searched online for examples, went through the reference manual of the `cut` command and tested it myself and remain unsure about the `-b` flag. There aren't any clear examples as to how the `cut -b` command works. Can someone create an example file and show how it is clearly used?

Comment: AFAIK it's currently no different from `cut -c` (since GNU Coreutils doesn't yet provide support for multi-byte characters)

Comment: What are you unsure about?

Comment: See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cut.1.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU software is described in `info` pages, so let’s see what `info cut` says:

> ‘-b BYTE-LIST’ ‘--bytes=BYTE-LIST’
>        Select for printing only the bytes in positions listed in
>        BYTE-LIST.  Tabs and backspaces are treated like any other
>        character; they take up 1 byte.  If an output delimiter is
>        specified, (see the description of ‘--output-delimiter’), then
>        output that string between ranges of selected bytes.
>
> ‘-c CHARACTER-LIST’ ‘--characters=CHARACTER-LIST’
>        Select for printing only the characters in positions listed in
>        CHARACTER-LIST.  **The same as ‘-b’ for now, but internationalization
>        will change that.**  Tabs and backspaces are treated like any other
>        character; they take up 1 character.  If an output delimiter is
>        specified, (see the description of ‘--output-delimiter’), then
>        output that string between ranges of selected bytes.

This is from coreutils 8.28 that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10, [adding multibyte support is in progress](https://crashcourse.housegordon.org/coreutils-multibyte-support.html) and may enable a different behaviour of these two options in the future.

`xxd -g1` shows hexdump byte equivalents of characters (after the colon) grouped bytewise as well as its ASCII representation on the left. Take as an example:

```bsh
$ printf a | xxd -g1
00000000: 61                                               a
$ printf á | xxd -g1
00000000: c3 a1                                            ..
```

`a` is a single-byte character with the hex equivalent 61, while `á` is a two-byte character with the hex equivalent c3 a1. Let’s see how `cut` from coreutils 8.28 behaves if we try to cut out the first byte or character respectively (`0a` is just a newline char added by `cut` and can be ignored):

```bsh
$ printf ab | cut -b1 | xxd -g1
00000000: 61 0a                                            a.
$ printf ab | cut -c1 | xxd -g1
00000000: 61 0a                                            a.
$ printf áb | cut -b1 | xxd -g1
00000000: c3 0a                                            .. # first byte of á
$ printf áb | cut -b2 | xxd -g1
00000000: a1 0a                                            .. # second byte of á
$ printf áb | cut -c1 | xxd -g1
00000000: c3 0a                                            .. # first byte of á
$ printf áb | cut -c2 | xxd -g1
00000000: a1 0a                                            .. # second byte of á
```

When it’s implemented, the expected behaviour is:

```bsh
$ printf ab | cut -b1 | xxd -g1
00000000: 61 0a                                            a.
$ printf ab | cut -c1 | xxd -g1
00000000: 61 0a                                            a.
$ printf áb | cut -b1 | xxd -g1
00000000: c3 0a                                            ..  # first byte of á
$ printf áb | cut -b2 | xxd -g1
00000000: a1 0a                                            ..  # second byte of á
$ printf áb | cut -c1 | xxd -g1
00000000: c3 a1 0a                                         ... # both bytes of á
$ printf áb | cut -c2 | xxd -g1
00000000: 62 0a                                            b.  # second char = b
```